# Matching and adding reg expression value in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contains a traceroute to a server. I want to extract the last router touched and compile the delay average.

I have tried the following but it only displays single **delay value**. How do I add the delays and get an average of the delays?.

**File contains trace:**

```
traceroute to 34.233.68.171 (34.233.68.171), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.458 ms  1.319 ms  1.236 ms
 2  173.230.125.21 (173.230.125.21)  9.911 ms  9.308 ms  9.702 ms
 3  99.82.176.202 (99.82.176.202)  9.616 ms  10.239 ms  10.095 ms
 4  54.239.104.28 (54.239.104.28)  31.762 ms  31.663 ms 54.239.104.88 (54.239.104.88)  32.679 ms
 5  54.239.104.23 (54.239.104.23)  28.090 ms 54.239.104.99 (54.239.104.99)  26.883 ms 54.239.104.63 (54.239.104.63)  30.373 ms
 6  * * *
 7  54.239.43.176 (54.239.43.176)  22.007 ms 54.240.229.173 (54.240.229.173)  27.092 ms 54.239.42.188 (54.239.42.188)  34.865 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  52.93.28.172 (52.93.28.172)  22.837 ms 52.93.28.194 (52.93.28.194)  31.958 ms 52.93.28.154 (52.93.28.154)  27.522 ms
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
36  * * *
```

**My code:**

```
import re

rgexpress = re.compile(r'\s\s\d\d?.\d\d\d+\s+ms') 
with open("new2") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = rgexpress.search(line)
        print(result)
```

My Result is:

```
None
<re.Match object; span=(28, 38), match='  1.458 ms'>
<re.Match object; span=(35, 45), match='  9.911 ms'>
<re.Match object; span=(33, 43), match='  9.616 ms'>
<re.Match object; span=(33, 44), match='  31.762 ms'>
<re.Match object; span=(33, 44), match='  28.090 ms'>
None
<re.Match object; span=(33, 44), match='  22.007 ms'>
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(31, 42), match='  22.837 ms'>
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Desired Result: 
'''
(22.837+31.958+27.522)/3 = 27.439‬
'''
**Average = 27.439‬**

Comment: Why not use a library like `csv` (maybe Pandas?) for this? Could you describe the format of the data? Which column contains the “delay value”?

Comment: I agree with Alexander, once in pandas, you can do all kinds of calculations

Comment: There is no CSV involved here, the data is the output of a traceroute command, which is exactly as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all matching delays on a line, convert them to float and calculate the mean:

```
import re

# some sample data
data = [
"7  54.239.43.176 (54.239.43.176)  22.007 ms 54.240.229.173 (54.240.229.173)  27.092 ms 54.239.42.188 (54.239.42.188)  34.865 ms",
"8  * * *"
]

re_delay = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d{3}(?= ms)')
for line in data:
    delays = [float(delay) for delay in re_delay.findall(line)]
    if delays:
        mean = sum(delays)/len(delays)
        print(mean)

# 27.988
```

Note that you should use `\d+`, as I did here, instead of `\d\d` for the integer part of the delay, otherwise any delay larger than 100 ms wouldn't be matched.

---

Edit to answer the question in your comment:

You could also build a list of the means:

```
re_delay = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d{3}(?= ms)')
out = []
for line in data:
    delays = [float(delay) for delay in re_delay.findall(line)]
    if delays:
        mean = sum(delays)/len(delays)
        out.append(mean)
```

and access the last one with

```
print(out[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. what if I had to extract line 18 only (aka last router touched) without using literal characters ?

Comment: You can put the outputs in a list and access the last one, see the edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

rgexpress = re.compile(r'\s\s\d\d?.\d\d\d+\s+ms') 
sum = 0
count = 0
with open("new2") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = rgexpress.search(line)
        if result:
            sum += float(result.group(0))
            count += 1
print(sum/count)
```

I hope edited version is better.